# Asp.net 5 WebApi 2.0 partial response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, httphandler

I'm working on LinQ to Entity, 
Here is my working code:

```
        var products = from p in AppContext.Products
                       join ... //joins tables
                       where ... //conditions
                       select p;

        var result = products.OrderBy(p => p.Name);

        //Move it to custom format.
        return result.Select(p => new
            {
                p.Id,
                p.Name,
                p.Description,
                ...
                /*This looks ugly and need to be moved out to somewhere else*/
                Categories = FindCategories(p.Id, true),
                MetaData = AppContext.ProductMetas.Where(pm => pm.ProductId == p.Id),
                Photos = AppContext.ProductPhotos.Where(pp => pp.ProductId == p.Id)
            }).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

However, I would like to move 'return new...' part into somewhere else (better inject asp.net api handler when transform object to json). For example:

```
//GetAll()
...
var products = from ... in ... select p;
return products;

//How to register some handler 
var results = new List<object>();
foreach (var product in resultSet) {
    //merge objects into result set
    results.Add(new {/*Merge properties together*/})
}
```

But I don't know how to do this. Anyone familiar with this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite clear on whether you need assistance with the actual mapping of the object in Linq to Entities or how to add this logic to an ASP.NET 5 route, I am assuming it is the latter.
One approach would be to create a DTO, that will contain the entity and relation data you require, like so:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

You will then need to create a controller to handle the request:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var products = //..make call to service or query to get products..

        var results = new List<ProductDTO>();
        foreach (var product in products) 
        {
            // merge objects into new ProductDTO collection
            results.Add(a=> new ProductDTO() {Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name ...});
        }
        return new JsonResult(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @corkington, actually I'm doing exactly like this. However, what I need here is:
`
//This should be dynamic fields. What if a client need only a "Name" now, and then it call another request and need "Code, Price, Quantity"? 
results.Add(a=> new ProductDTO() {Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name ...}); 
`